# Simple MySQL table design

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I think I should be counted as database newbie, so read the question as a newbie question. I currently create a table, which holds environment variables for a number of hosts, like this:

```
create table envs ( 
  host varchar(255), 
  envname varchar(255), 
  envvalue varchar(8192), 
  PRIMARY KEY(host, envname)
);
```

Very simple, one table holding all the data I need. Common operation is to get all the environment variables for a given host, another is to get a given environment variable for a given host, third example operation would be to get a given environment variable for all hosts and list duplicates.

Performance is not expected to be an issue, it's going to be maybe tens of hosts, dozens of variables per host, average max 1 query per second.

Now I've read that having composite primary key is not necessarily a good idea. Is this true for above use case? If it is true, how should I change the database design? If not, is the above one-table database fine for the purposes I listed above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a problem here with the primary key. The semantics of a primary key is to uniquely identify the non-key attribute values for the key values. As I assume that for one host and one envname there is at most one envvalue the primary key makes perfect sense.

It could be that some people argue against composite primary keys because they are afraid of performance issues. However performance considerations should never influence the choice of the primary key. Many database systems automatically create an index structure for the primary key; the choice of this index structure can influence performance. However this choice can mostly be changed manually and should be done at a later point if you really have performance issues.

Your one-table design and choice of primary key is fine.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I've read that having composite primary key is not necessarily a good idea. Is this true for above use case?

No.  Use a composite primary key on `(host, envname)`.

> If it is true, how should I change the database design?

N/A.

> If not, is the above one-table database fine for the purposes I listed above?

Yes: it's known as the [Entity–Attribute–Value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad idea, because you store **unique** values (host, envname) **several** times.

What if you were to change the hostname from *srv01* to *srv01_new*? You'd have to change **every** ocurrence of *srv01* in your table. And what if, some day, you decide you need to create a new table that holds additional information about every single host.

Now, if you change the hostname, you have to change those information as well.

To get to your question: It's not an issue of **performance**, but of **normalization**.

Databases should generally be normalized as far as possible. If you are intrigued enough, [read on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

You should create one table for your hosts, having a unique **id** (int) as primary key and a unique (index) **name** as the hostname.

Your table should then only reference the **id** of the host, not the **name**. This way, your hostname is only stored *once* in your whole database and can be altered to whatever you desire, without breaking other tables.

---

If your environment names are unique, too, you should create another table for those, having the same layout as the hosts table (id, name).

Your combination table then stores the *id of the host* and the *id of the environment*, along with the value. You must of course keep the combined primary key, so every combination of host/environment is unique and easily indexable.

Then, you have a many-to-many-relationship with additional attributes and perfect normalization.

Comment: Sounds unnecssarily complex to me... With the 1 table I now have `insert into envs values ('TestHost1', 'MSG_SUBJECT', 'Test Host');`. If I instead had 3 tables, `hosts`, `envnames`, `envmapping`, how would I do that insertion, when all 3 strings are user input kind of thing?

Comment: Yes, normalized tables are more complex to maintain. But the benefits of having a normalized table will become very clear to you, once you are in the peril of having to modify anything on your database. To insert, you have to first insert a host and an environment. Then, you get the IDs of those by using the API of your database. This IDs is then inserted, along with the value, to the cross table.

Of course, you can still do it your way. But keep in mind that you have been warned(tm) when your whole database concept goes bonkers on the next change request.

Comment: Actually `insert` statement complexity is fine, even if it means adding transactions etc. I'm more concerned about complexity of `select` statements, since those will (at least initially) be written into configuration by users as strings. Would "view" solve this for me, ie. with right view, user could do their query without multi-table joins etc?

Comment: What normal form does the proposed schema violate? I cannot see any violation of either 1NF, 2NF, 3NF, or BCNF.

Comment: You are right, from the formal definition of normalization, the schema doesn't violate anything. Still, using verbose primary keys is *in most cases* a bad idea because you can never completely assure that you will **never** change those values in the future. Numeric IDs are so generic (and have the benefit of being auto-incremented and therefore assuredly unique) that you never have to change those.

Comment: I wouldn't say so for multiple reasons: a) it is perfectly fine to change a primary key (pk) - if another relation's column references the pk it should have a foreign key (fk) constraint with an 'on update cascade' construct so that a change to the pk propagates to fk relation; b) numeric ids are generic but that is THE reason it makes them flawed in relational design - why should, e.g., a person be better identified by some weird number than their SSN (I give you credit that the SSN itself is a weird number but why add yet another indirection ;)); my argument continues in the next comment.

Comment: continuation from the previous comment. c) if you argue to use numeric ids instead of verbose pks for performance reasons, I can tell you that not every DBMS handles non-numeric pks as badly as, e.g, MySQL - it can even be the case that the additional indirection (index lookup on the 'verbose pk' -> generated pk) creates a bottleneck in other DBMSs; d) lastly, if you are afraid that your pk is not really unique than this is a relational design issue and for all other cases, the DBMS ensures that pks, generated or not, are always unique (index lookup).

Comment: I see your point. I, too, mostly favor "speaking" design over IDs and the likes. But explaining foreign keys, constraints and triggers is mostly more difficult than to argue for the use of IDs. Of course, if you use everyhting the DB gives you (FK+constraints), you don't really need foreign keys. But unfortunately, most people don't do so and so I the first advise I give is always to use generic IDs. Because it's simpler ^^